# Check string in Knockout JS and then split string values

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following data binding:

```
$row().current_tracking
```

Sometimes *$row().current_tracking* has a value of, for example:

```
372424561624
```

And sometimes *$row().current_tracking* have a value with two numbers separated with a comma, for example:

```
372424561624, 324562345
```

1. First I need to check if there is one or two numbers.
2. If there are two numbers separated with a comma, I need to split them into two strings, e.g *$strNo1* and *$strNo2*, otherwise just use *$strNo1*.
3. If two numbers and strings, check their length.

Then I need to check their lengths. Long numbers = *DHL* and short numbers = *UPS*.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

you could use a [Custom Binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to transform your string depending on its content.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.checkComma = {    
  init: (element, valueAccessor) => {
    const value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())
      .split(',')
      .filter((x) => x?.trim().length > 0)
      .map((x) => x.trim())
      .join(',')
      .replace(',', '<br>');
    element.innerHTML = value;    
  },
};

class ViewModel {
  constructor() {
    this.rows = ko.observableArray([
      { current_tracking: ko.observable('372424561624, 324562345') },
      { current_tracking: ko.observable(', 372424561624') },
      { current_tracking: ko.observable('372424561624, ') }, 
      { current_tracking: ko.observable(' 372424561624, ') },
      { current_tracking: ko.observable('372424561624,') },
    ]);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.js" integrity="sha512-2AL/VEauKkZqQU9BHgnv48OhXcJPx9vdzxN1JrKDVc4FPU/MEE/BZ6d9l0mP7VmvLsjtYwqiYQpDskK9dG8KBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.rows, as: '$row' }">
  <li data-bind="checkComma: $row.current_tracking"></li>
</ul>
```